# Qual é o correto: re-execução ou reexecução?

Tags: português-brasileiro, hífen

Em português brasileiro, de acordo com a nova gramática, coloca-se o hífen em palavras quando têm duas vogais?

Então, qual é o correto: re-execução ou reexecução?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O correto é **reexecução**.

> ```
> (re- + execução)
>     substantivo feminino
>     .Ato ou efeito de reexecutar (ex.: foi estabelecido um prazo para a reexecução do serviço).
> ```

Há algumas regras para saber quando deve ou não usar o hífen.

---

#### Letras iguais

Palavras que começam com a última *vogal* do prefixo, sempre são separadas pelo hífen, *exceto* nos prefixos `CO-`, `RE-`, `PRE`, por exemplo:

```
┌──────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┐
│Anti-inflamatório │ O prefixo termina com `i` e a palavra começa com `i` │ Iguais     │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│Extraoficial      │ O prefixo termina com `a` e apalavra começa com `o`  │ Diferentes │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│Reexecução        │ Utiliza a exceção `RE-`                              │ Exceção    │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

---

#### Palavras com `H`

Em palavras iniciadas por **H**, *sempre* que houver um prefixo, ambos deverão ser separados pelo hífen, por exemplo:

```
┌──────────────┐
│Super-Herói   │
├──────────────┤
│Anti-Higiênico│
└──────────────┘
```

---

#### Palavras com `R` ou `S`

Palavras iniciadas com `R` ou `S` devem ser separadas pelo hífen somente quando o prefixo terminar com consoante. Quando o prefixo termina com vogal, o `R` ou `S` deve ser "dobrado", por exemplo:

```
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│Sub-reino        │ O prefixo termina com consoante e a palavra começa com `R` │ Hífen       │
│─────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│Inter-resistente │ O prefixo termina com consoante e a palavra começa com `R` │ Hífen       │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│Antissocial      │ O prefixo termina com vogal e a palavra começa com `S`     │ Dobra o `S` │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│Corréu           │ O prefixo termina com vogal e a palavra começa com `R`     │ Dobra o `R` │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

---

#### Prefixo `sub-`

Palavras com o prefixo `sub-`, contém hífen *apenas* quando a palavra começa com `R`, `B` ou `H`, por exemplo:

```
┌───────────────┐
│Sub-Reino      │
├───────────────┤
│Sub-Betuminoso │
├───────────────┤
│Sub-Humano     │
├───────────────┤
│Subatômico     │
└───────────────┘
```

---

#### Prefixos Tônicos

Sempre que o prefixo for tônico (*pré-*, *pós-* e *pró-*), ele deverá ser separado por hífen, por exemplo:

```
┌───────────────┐
│Pós-operatório │
├───────────────┤
│Pré-estreia    │
├───────────────┤
│Pré-natal      │
├───────────────┤
│Pré-sal        │
└───────────────┘
```

<sup>Referências:</sup>
<sup>https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/reexecu%C3%A7%C3%A3o</sup>
<sup>https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/uso-do-hifen-descomplicado/</sup>
<sup>https://novaescola.org.br/conteudo/328/regras-hifen-alteradas-novo-acordo-ortografico</sup>